# Connotations of 兔子它爹/兔子的爹?

Tags: meaning

I was watching [episode 2 of 戳锅漏](https://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTMwMzI3MjI0.html?spm=a2h0k.11417342.soresults.dselectbutton&s=e74195de5e6311e0a046) when I came across this sentence

> [image]
>
> 兔子的爹跑得还快

[This question](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/587298614.html) on Baidu Zhidao also talks about something similar, asking:

> 我的团长我的团中 有一句话叫 王连胜 你就是兔子他爹 是什麽意思啊[？]

One answer says:

> 骂人说：“你比兔子的爹还跑的快。“
>   该明白了吧？

---

The variant 兔子它爹 also seems somewhat common.

The book《[转世英豪](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=EOy1CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT78&lpg=PT78&dq=%22%E5%85%94%E5%AD%90%E5%AE%83%E7%88%B9%E2%80%9C&source=bl&ots=BkqPiddlF9&sig=f6OIC0aUAdovi4R3Z77fErKyZWY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGuqeXk67fAhUewcQHHVnPCQIQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%E5%85%94%E5%AD%90%E5%AE%83%E7%88%B9%E2%80%9C&f=false)》has the line:

> 他在心裏慶倖自己比兔子它爹還跑的快

and the book《[符剑录](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=jSADBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT89&lpg=PT89&dq=%22%E5%85%94%E5%AD%90%E5%AE%83%E7%88%B9%E2%80%9C&source=bl&ots=Vrw8RsUBzO&sig=pam5k__pegWM8wG_64c3vMXiagQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGuqeXk67fAhUewcQHHVnPCQIQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%E5%85%94%E5%AD%90%E5%AE%83%E7%88%B9%E2%80%9C&f=false)》has the line:

> 妈的!那臭小子跑哪儿去了,比兔子它爹跑的还快。

There is also this entry on [Jianshu](https://www.jianshu.com/p/3946bec9d39b) which has a comment at the bottom that reads:

> 我们刚上四楼走廊，后来不知道怎么了，那两个女生突然跑得比兔子它爹还快！一边跑还一边叫，我正纳闷呢，然后我一回头——我们后面跟着一个黑...

---

The TV show is in Sichuanese, but the phrase itself seems *very* Northeastern, yet I'm not sure.

The fact that people claim that you can use this to 骂人 is also somewhat confusing.

What connotations does 兔子它爹/兔子的爹 have?

Comment: Gut feeling: the meaning isn't that deep; given that 兔子 means something like *rascal*, and rabbits run fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

你比兔子跑得还快 is a common expression, since we all know 兔子 are fast.

他爹 is acting like a 'damn' without cursing.

You run even faster than a damn rabbit.

Another meaning:

Rabbit are fast, the father of rabbit would be treated as faster, this similar expression are very common in Chinese.

Compare 你比老母猪还能吃. to 你比猪还能吃.

A pig mom sounds like 更能吃.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little interesting convention in Chinese language. First, the screenshot you have, should actually be

> 表哥，你比兔子的爹跑得还快

To see what it means, let us go step by step. First

> 表哥，你比兔子得还快

It is straightforward and it means you run faster than rabbits, which run very fast, as we all know.

Then by using it from time to time, you are not feeling satisfied as before, you say

> 表哥，你比兔子的爹跑得还快

This time, you run even faster than rabbit's father! We know if for an adult rabbit, its father may become old and does not run faster. But, notice, the father here is not referring to a specific rabbit's father, it is referring to this creature's "father"! And it simply means whatever creature that runs faster than rabbits!

As for regions using this expression, I am not quite sure. Personally, I am from Shaanxi and I do not hear people using this.

Comment: Simply say : "you should know how to do it"  is enough;  if you want to be funny, you can say: "you (and your mother) should know how to do it" --I meant even your mother who is not holding this job knows what this job is about, there is no excuse for you to not  know it. Yes, I heard people say thing this way.

Comment: @TangHo Is it *你妈都知道怎么做* in Chinese?

Comment: I never heard it in Chinese, Just my boss like to say things like this, sometimes it would be "Now you and your mothers all have name tags, don't let me see you without one". If translate to Chinese, it would be " 現在(你和你媽)都有名字牌... (even your mother doesn't work here got one, so you must have one. It is funny in it's absurdity)

Comment: @TangHo I see, so it is an expression in English.

Comment: Update: Just heard someone in a Podcast  said: "Everyone and their brothers are running for that seat in this election" --It seems the person beside you can be anyone. I imagine it would be alright to say "Everyone and their dogs get a flu shot"